# Windows 7 x86_64 and an authenticating proxy causes issues with Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, proxy

I am having trouble getting Google Chrome to work suitably behind an authenticating proxy. Chrome was working on Windows XP behind the same proxy... and on another machine with Windows 7 x86_64 with no proxy.

My [support ticket](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=02aac6ce69e01ed0&hl=en) explains the situation in more detail, and others have conferred the same problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: Try to uninstall the Chrome with the REVO uninstaller and then reboot the system and then again try to install. And also try to download the new and updated setup from the site and try to install it.

Comment: @avirik - links for uninstaller and updated setup? Also - you should add an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Sometimes its good to comment rather than post an answer. Not for reputation I like to help and I'll provide you the link sure.

Comment: I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`As user mention in comment for answer`

If you're downloading Chrome for your own user account only, use this installer: [Alternate installer for one user account](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1)

If you're downloading Chrome for all user accounts on your computer, use this installer: [Alternate installer for all user](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?system=true)

And try to uninstall the Google chrome with [REVO Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) uninstaller and delete all registries through it. And then reboot it. However it will not prompt you to do so but restart manually and then re-install the setup.

Comment: this did not solve the issue.